Script Runs Without Errors Locally but Fails in GitLab CI/CD Pipeline on GCP
When I run this script on my local machine, there are no errors. However, in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline, it produces error messages.
local
cic
Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file. I would like to understand what might be causing this issue.
gitlab.yml
Is anyone know about this situation ?
Or what gcp setting i need to inspect?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Could you please align the question with the "Help others reproduce the problem" section on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
